# How to use Tkinter or any other python GUI with Scrapy

Tags: tkinter, web-scraping, scrapy

I want a gui with Tkinter or any other python GUI with scrapy. So the scraped links and data should be displayed On gui rather than Command Prompt

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any Tkinter (or Qt/GTK) GUIs for Scrapy, but you can certainly create your own.

Most Scrapy GUIs or integrations come in the form of webclients, some of which I have seen are

- [Scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)
- [Portia](https://github.com/scrapinghub/portia)
- [SpiderKeeper](https://github.com/DormyMo/SpiderKeeper)

and maybe

- https://github.com/stav/scrapybox

To interact with Scrapy, and create your own GUI, you have the choices between

1. creating an Extension inside your Scrapy project, which then interacts with your GUI (but you'll have to start/run the crawler yourself, first, somehow).
   For this you'll want to look at the [`scrapy-jsonrpc`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-jsonrpc) project as an example.
   Another alternative (with http interactions) is [`scrapy-rt`](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scrapyrt).
   You may want to look at "[Scrapy as a script](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script)" (for scripting the run) as well.
2. creating a wrapping program which starts the crawler and then interfaces with it.
   This is what [Scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) does (it takes a scrapy project uploaded as a python `egg` and works with that).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a project I found a long time ago when I was looking to do the same.

[HirojiSawatari's Github - "FindGoods"](https://github.com/HirojiSawatari/FindGoods)

[HirojiSawatari's Project Documentation/blog](http://www.katouspace.com/2016/12/19/3/)

There might be some... encoding issues lol.

The Idea is there though, if you reverse engineer the project, you should get an Idea on how to achieve what you want. It does entail proficiency with Tkinter and scrapy (obviously lol I mention because it isn't something for people just learning these frameworks.)